# Parsing wchar_t xml using Microsoft WebServices

Tags: web-services, visual-c++, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a wide character string using WebServices.

```
HRESULT hr = NOERROR;
WS_ERROR* error = NULL;
WS_XML_READER* xmlReader = NULL;

// Create an error object for storing rich error information
hr = WsCreateError(
    NULL,
    0,
    &error);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto Exit;
}

// Create an XML reader
hr = WsCreateReader(
    NULL,
    0,
    &xmlReader,
    error);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto Exit;
}


WCHAR* xml =
    L"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>"
    "<Orders xmlns='http://example.com'>"
    "<!-- Order #1 -->"
    "<PurchaseOrder id='1'>"
    "<Quantity>42</Quantity>"
    "<ProductName>Toaster</ProductName>"
    "</PurchaseOrder>"
    "<!-- Order #2 -->"
    "<PurchaseOrder id='2'>"
    "<Quantity>5</Quantity>"
    "<ProductName><![CDATA[Block&Tackle]></ProductName>"
    "</PurchaseOrder>"
    "</Orders>";
BYTE* bytes = (BYTE*)xml;
ULONG byteCount = (ULONG)wcslen(xml) * sizeof(WCHAR);

// Setup the source input
WS_XML_READER_BUFFER_INPUT bufferInput;
ZeroMemory(&bufferInput, sizeof(bufferInput));
bufferInput.input.inputType = WS_XML_READER_INPUT_TYPE_BUFFER;
bufferInput.encodedData = bytes;
bufferInput.encodedDataSize = byteCount;

// Setup the source encoding
WS_XML_READER_TEXT_ENCODING textEncoding;
ZeroMemory(&textEncoding, sizeof(textEncoding));
textEncoding.encoding.encodingType = WS_XML_READER_ENCODING_TYPE_TEXT;
textEncoding.charSet = WS_CHARSET_AUTO;

// Setup the reader
hr = WsSetInput(xmlReader, &textEncoding.encoding, &bufferInput.input, NULL, 0, error);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto Exit;
}
```

I've also tried to change `textEncoding.charSet = WS_CHARSET_AUTO;` to `textEncoding.charSet = WS_CHARSET_UTF16LE;`

The above code keeps failing while calling to WsReadNode (in the attached link), and the error message is "The data input was not in the expected format or did not have the expected value".

[WsReadNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dd430596(v=vs.94))

I can't convert the **WCHAR** array to **CHAR** array as the XML may contain non ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example xml has an encoding in the declaration

```
 L"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>"
```

Changing it to

```
L"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16LE' standalone='yes'?>"
```

should fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/webservices/ns-webservices-ws_xml_reader_buffer_input

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/webservices/ns-webservices-ws_xml_reader_text_encoding

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/webservices/ns-webservices-_ws_xml_reader_encoding

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/webservices/ne-webservices-ws_xml_reader_encoding_type

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/webservices/ne-webservices-ws_charset

For example on this ultimate you should use `WS_CHARSET_UTF8` because on your XML you put encoding UTF8.

About ASCII, what about make something to replace non ASCII values to ASCII values ?

If you have problems with WCHAR to CHAR conversion, on this site you have a lot of info about this.